# Custom Content type manipulation

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am building a Drupal 7 website and I am relatively new to it. (1 month old). What I have done is created a custom content type that has several textarea fields within it.

Some of them are mandatory while others are not mandatory. Admins can go ahead and create contents while deciding what fields are mandatory and what fields are not and they accordingly appear along with nodes once created.

The problem: I want to allow the admins control over how this content is rendered in terms of HTML markup.

For instance, the default order of the content type is:

1. Title
2. Description (No body tag)
3. Example
4. Steps

But I want the admins to have the power to reorganize the above renderings anywhere they want on the screen and be able to reorganize this content the way they want to.

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/ds

Try Display Suite

You may also checkout their youtube channel to see if it was suitable for you.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648